# Interceptor for validating XML request in REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf, interceptor

I am developing a REST API which is a **@POST** and **@Consumes** both **MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** . I need to implement validations for the incoming request. I don't want to have Bean Level validation JSR-303. I need to have a Validation class which handles all the validations and i need to configure interceptor for the incoming XML request before Unmarshalling. I looked into Apache cxf interceptors and it is mainly if you are enabling the Bean Validations. How shall i do it?

Comment: There is  `BeanValidationFeature` which needs to be enabled. If you are using xml based configuration, you have to inject this feature like this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/features.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way how to do this without the usage of BeanValidationFeature.

```
public class YourFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

     @Override
      public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final InputStream inputStream = request.getEntityStream();
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outStream);
            byte[] requestEntity = outStream.toByteArray();
            if (requestEntity.length == 0) {
                builder.append("");
            } else {
                builder.append(new String(requestEntity,"UTF-8"));
                request.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
                setRequest(builder.toString());
                validateYourRequest(builder.toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.TRACE,"Error occured while converting the request into Stream",ex.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

And in application.context.xml

```
<bean id="YourFilter" class="com.test.YourFilter"/>

<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.test.YourController" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" /> 
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />  
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="jaxbXmlProvider" />
        <ref bean="YourFilter"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```